# Storybook React native

Tags: react-native, storybook

I'm currently writing a storybook UI library for react native. I'm browsing various addons and am looking for suggestions for react-native addons.

Can anyone suggest anything that would integrate with figma and help with creating documentation?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by adding the `storybook-addon-designs` library. Refer to [Storybook-and-Figma](https://help.figma.com/hc/en-us/articles/360045003494-Storybook-and-Figma) for more information.